# Get the Beta from a regression model

Tags: python, linear-regression

I am using python to calculate a linear regression from a dataframe.

I would like to know how get just the beta of the equation, in order to return to the inial dataframe ?

Using this function, I can get the beta:

```
lm = smf.ols("np.log(Volume) ~ np.log(PrecoVenda)", data=df2).fit()

 print(lm.params)

Intercept             5.435106
np.log(PrecoVenda)    0.819627
dtype: float64
```

How to select just the beta from the equation ?

Comment: try `lm.params[1]`

Comment: Great !
Thank you